# Can't add comments social plugin to my HTML5 webpage

Tags: facebook, html, comments

I have a problem putting the new HTML5 comments social plugin in my webpage.

I put the flowing code after the body tag but nothing happens for FF 8.0

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8/>
        <title>Aromáticas do Vez - Site em Construção</title>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Style/style_1.css" TYPE="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div id="logo">
            <a class="centro" href="index.html">
                <img id="img_logo" src="Imagens/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo"/>
            </a>
            <p>Site em Construção /!\</p>
        </div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Aromaticas-do-Vez/165471416842939" data-num-posts="1" data-width="500"></div>         
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you do not have an app Id specified. I would recommend creating a Facebook Application at https://developers.facebook.com/apps and then re-generating the code for your comments plugin at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ .

When you regenerate the code, the application ID should get automatically included at the end of the line that starts with "js.src = "